# iFrameExtractor EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ffmpeg

When using the iFrameExtractor for iOS I have been getting the "EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=0x8) error on this line:

```
- (AVPacket*)readPacket {

    if (_currentPacket.size > 0 || _inBuffer) return &_currentPacket;

    NSMutableData *packetData = [audioPacketQueue objectAtIndex:0];
    _packet = [packetData mutableBytes];

    // NSLog(@"got audio stream");
    **if (_packet->dts != AV_NOPTS_VALUE) {**
        _packet->dts += av_rescale_q(0, AV_TIME_BASE_Q, _audioStream->time_base);
    }
    if (_packet->pts != AV_NOPTS_VALUE) {
        _packet->pts += av_rescale_q(0, AV_TIME_BASE_Q, _audioStream->time_base);
    }
    // NSLog(@"ready with audio");


    [audioPacketQueueLock lock];
    audioPacketQueueSize -= _packet->size;
    [audioPacketQueue removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    [audioPacketQueueLock unlock];



    _currentPacket = *(_packet);

    return &_currentPacket;   
}
```

Comment: That's why you get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`...
Check `packetData` & `audioPacketQueue`

Comment: @Larme so basically I'd have to do if `(!_packet && !audioPacketQueue) return nil;` ?

Comment: That could do the trick. But you may want to know why _packet or audioPacketQueue (objectAtIndex:0) is nil, and maybe manage the case before.

Comment: @Larme Well I've noticed that it only happens when the video is about 2-3 seconds long or their is no sound.

Comment: Did you try what I suggest?

Comment: @Larme I did, but nothing ever ended up happening with it. When I find that the object is nil, I try rerunning it at that point but still returns nothing.